# Invoking scala classes which extends traits during runtime

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am relatively new to scala so please bear me if I asked silly questions.
I have a requirement where I need to invoke a method run time.

I have a trait which is being extended by two classes

```
trait Animal {
   def walk():DataFrame
}
```

This is extended by two classes.

```
class Dog(sparkSession: SparkSession) extends Animal {
   def walk():DataFrame = {
      .............
   }
}

class Cat(sparkSession: SparkSession) extends Animal {
   def walk():DataFrame = {
      .............
   }
}
```

Now from a config file I will get a list of these class names

Lets say like this

```
val animals = ["com.xy.Dog","com.xy.Cat"]
```

I need to invoke these classes and execute walk methods.
Can I do something like this?

```
animals.forEach{ animalString =>
   val animalObject = Class.forName(animalString ).newInstance().asInstanceOf(Animal)
   animalObject.walk
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: I get a compilation error:
"T0 does not take parameters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues, let's take them one by one:

To build a list in scala you need to do:

```scala
val animals = List("com.xy.Dog", "com.xy.Cat")
```

The `forEach` method is actually `foreach`, so there's a small typo. Finally, when you call the `newInstance` you should get the appropriate constructor before that, otherwise it will use the default one.

```scala
animals.foreach { animalString =>
  val animalObject = Class.forName(animalString)
    .getConstructor(classOf[DataFrame]) // Get the constructor for a DataFrame argument
    .newInstance(dataframe)             // Pass the dataframe instance
    .asInstanceOf[Animal]
  animalObject.walk
}
```

I've made a couple of small changes to the code for you to see it working. You can run the app to see the output:

```scala
class Dog extends Animal {
  def walk(): Unit = { println("I'm a dog.") }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  def walk(): Unit = { println("I'm a cat.") }
}

object AnimalTest extends App {
  val animals = List("com.xy.Dog", "com.xy.Cat")
  animals.foreach { animalString =>
    val animalObject = Class.forName(animalString)
      .newInstance()
      .asInstanceOf[Animal]
    animalObject.walk
  }
}
```

Note that I've removed the constructor arguments here to easily build instances. The rest is about the same. I hope this helps you.

Comment: that is awesome. It worked perfect for me. Yeah the list was being read from a config and yes earlier I used JavaList and now I converted to ScalaList where Java list uses forEach and ScalaList uses foreach. Thank you very much for these details